# Installing the third OS

Tags: boot

I have a laptop which had Windows 7 pre-installed. I did dual boot it with Ubuntu 12.04 and I have never since booted to windows. What happens now if I install the third OS, Fedora 17 or Opensuse 12.2 by CD? Will the next installed OS become the default or will I be able to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer for the OS may give you the option to not install a boot loader, in which case it would not take over.  The norm is to take over, and usually install GRUB and recognize the other OSes and provide the choice to boot into them.

Comment: Any idea of a distro that don't take over. I'm curious and would like some more flavors.